# Release for VLC 2.2.1

Tags: vlc

I'm running Debian 8 (Jessie), and I've been waiting for months and months for vlc 2.2.1 to come out. Is there a way I can track the package (in terms of what phase it's currently in) so I can get an idea how long it's going to take?

Answer (score 0):

[tracker.debian.org](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/vlc) is the closest answer I have. Contacting the maintainers via that link might get someone who has a better idea.